# How do I send i send an gmail api request- i did all the authentication steps but i hit a wall

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, passport.js, gmail-api

I am trying to construct a Gmail replica but I've hit a roadblock in terms of making requests to Gmail API-

here's my code:
index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
require("./passport-setup");
const CLIENT_URL = "http://localhost:3000/inbox"
const passportSetup = require("./passport-setup");
const GoogleStrategy = require("./passport-setup").OAuth2Strategy;
var { gmail } = require('@googleapis/gmail');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
   
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["key1", "key2"],
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));
app.get("/failed", (req, res) => res.send("Failed!"));

// GET /auth/google
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  The first step in Google authentication will involve
//   redirecting the user to google.com.  After authorization, Google
//   will redirect the user back to this application at /auth/google/callback
app.get("/google", passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile',
      'email',
      'https://mail.google.com/'
  ],
  accessType: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent'
  
  }))
// GET /auth/google/callback
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
app.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google", {
  successRedirect: CLIENT_URL, 
  failureRedirect: "/failed"
}))

app.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/failed" }),
);
app.get("/success", (req, res)=>{
  if(req.user) {
      res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: "Login success!",
          user: req.user,
          cookies: req.cookies
  });
};
});


app.get('/inbox', (req, res)=> {
  gmail.users.messages.list({ 
    userId: 'me', 
    auth: oauth2Client,
    id: message.id,
    format: "full",
    pageToken: nextPageToken,
  }, function(err, response) {
      res.send(response);
    });
});

app.get("/logout", (req,res)=>{
  req.logout();
  res.redirect(CLIENT_URL);
})
app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`Server running at port ${5000}!`));
```

passport-setup.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in Passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an accessToken, refreshToken, and Google
//   profile), and invoke a callback with a user object.
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: "insert client-id",
      clientSecret: "insert client secret",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
```

As seen in the following code I'm trying to pull out gmail.users.messages.list but have only been responded to with: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messages')".

me trying to request gmail.users.messages.list:

```
app.get('/inbox', (req, res)=> {
  gmail.users.messages.list({ 
    userId: 'me', 
    auth: oauth2Client,
    id: message.id,
    format: "full",
    pageToken: nextPageToken,
  }, function(err, response) {
      res.send(response);
    });
});
```